# Duration calculation in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a problem that I would solve if possible in Hive. 
The data is like the following:

```
action    timestamp
a         2014-01-01 10:00:00
b         2014-01-01 10:05:00
started   2014-01-01 10:06:00
c         2014-01-01 10:06:10
d         2014-01-01 10:56:00
paused    2014-01-01 11:15:00
e         2014-01-01 12:00:00
```

We can now calculate the duration between each timestamp using LAG(), however we would like to add columns which calculates duration for those actions BEFORE the "started", and actions AFTER the "started", but if paused then 0.
The final table should look like the following:

```
action    timestamp               duration_before_started  play_duration_after_started
a         2014-01-01 10:00:00     00:05:00                 00:00:00
b         2014-01-01 10:05:00     00:01:00                 00:00:00
started   2014-01-01 10:06:00     00:00:00                 00:00:10
c         2014-01-01 10:06:10     00:00:00                 00:39:50
d         2014-01-01 10:56:00     00:00:00                 00:19:00
paused    2014-01-01 11:15:00     00:00:00                 00:00:00
e         2014-01-01 12:00:00     00:00:00                 00:00:00
```

Is this possible in Hive within a reasonable computation time?

Best regards

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Unsure on how timely it will be as much of the parallel processing functionality of HDFS will be negated with the row operation, but it can be done.

Sounds like you just need to use case statements to determine when action is "started" to determine if the output needs to go to duration_before_started or play_duration_after_started. Then it is as simple as using some of the unix_timestamp, from_unixtime, and second functions to make the calculation.

Some documentation on these date functions are located here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF